# Setting Fancybox2 width/height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to use fancybox v2 to show a div whose contents are generated dynamically. I set the size of the div quite late in the scheme of things. I have tried the examples from fancybox's documentation for displaying divs whose size is fixed. It looks like this:

```
<a id="fancy" href="#showdiv">Show contents of div.</a>
<div id="showdiv">...</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancy").fancybox({autoSize:false, width: W, height: H, ...});
});
</script>
```

What I want is `W=$("#showdiv").width` and `H=$("#showdiv").height`. Obviously, H and W are not available to me at document ready. How do I go about doing this?

EDIT: Here is the html for the content div:

```
<div id="hidediv" style="display:none">
    <div id="showdiv" style="display:block;position:relative">
        <canvas id="mycanvas" style="position:relative;display:block"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

In a click handler of the anchor "#fancy" I do:

```
function onclick() {
    var jcanvas = $("#mycanvas").css('width', some_width).css('height', some_height);
    // draw on canvas
}
```

"#fancy" is the one associated with Fancybox.

Comment: `I set the size of the div quite late` : so it does have a size (at least `width`), doesn't it? If that is correct, then you don't need to set `width` and `height` and `autoSize:false` in fancybox options, they are calculated automatically despite the `div` is added a later time

Comment: @JFK I tried that but I have seen that if I don't set the values, the pop up has the wrong width(always about 100). Resizing the browser forces the box to readjust to correct widthxheight.

Comment: could you post the rendered html of the dynamically added `div` (#showdiv)? and, how do you set its size : dynamically? via css? you would need to provide extensive information if you want to get help ;)

Comment: @JFK added a stripped down version of my html

Comment: so, do you actually do `<a id="fancy" href="#showdiv" onclick="onclick();">Show</a>`? I guess it would be easier to pass the size of the canvas via a fancybox callback rather `onclick` attribute on the anchor

Comment: @JFK Well, it's a little more complicated :). I do a HTTP POST request in `onclick` and the response contains the width and height. I adjust the canvas in the success handler for the request. A call back would be the way to go. Is it possible to specify a callback and how? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I meant a callback to set Fancybox width/height in the success handler for the POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this function handles the response of your `HTTP POST`

```
function onclick() {
    // set size of canvas
    var jcanvas = $("#mycanvas").css({
        "width": some_width, // variable from response ?
        "height": some_height
    });
    // draw on canvas
}
```

... then call that function using the fancybox `afterLoad` callback like

```
$("#fancy").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // the box won't be scaled to fit the view port (optional)
    afterLoad: onclick()
});
```

**EDIT** :

Another option is to handle both, the canvas and fancybox within the same function using jQuery `.on()` so if you have

```
<a id="fancy" href="#showdiv">Show contents of div</a>
```

use this script :

```
$("#fancy").on("click", function () {
    // do HTTP POST
    // on success, get size form response
    var some_width = 300,
        some_height = 180;
    // set canvas size
    var jcanvas = $("#mycanvas").css({
        // variables from response
        "width": some_width, 
        "height": some_height
    });
    // draw on canvas
    //
    // then open fancybox ($(this) = #showdiv )
    $.fancybox($(this),{
        // API options etc
        fitToView: false
    });
});
```

in this case you don't need any callback.

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6XNV2/)** for documentation purposes.

Comment: Cool! I will try that and let you know. Thanks.